# Are there other types of Elves in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, elves, house-elves

In the Harry Potter universe, we obviously know of House-elves. They have their own brand of powerful magic etc.

In general I love the thought of Elves as beings, ergo:

**Is there any mention of *other* types of Elves in the Harry-Potter universe**

I ask this as Dobby, Winky and Kreacher are specifically called *House*-Elves.

Could there be Wood-Elves, Night-Elves etc?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Genuinely there could be, but it has never been said in canon. Rowling has never said there *isn't* but she's given no inclination that there is, either. There's nothing about it in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* or in any Harry Potter book. The House-elves resemble Brownies or Domovoi or all number of mythical beings: the use of the word elf is more akin to little people than Tolkien-esque elves.

Their magic is perfect for cleaning and running errands (apparation where it is magically blocked would allow them to run errands for their masters) and they are called *house*-elves. I have often wondered if they aren't natural, and were in fact bred by wizards as a slave race. If this is true, for example, (and this last bit is purely speculation on my part) then it would make sense that there's no other type of elf. This second paragraph is not supported by canon though, just something to think about.

To summarise, Rowling has never given any inclination of there being any other form of elf, nor would such elves fit the setting nor her use of the term; but on the other hand, she hasn't explicitly said that there are no other forms of elf.

Comment: +1 for "Domovoi". I wouldn't be surprised if that's where JKR got the name inspiration - for those not fluent in Russian, they are magical beings somewhat  similar to house-elves aside from being associated with a dwelling and not a House of SomePurebloods. Their name literally translates as "of the house".

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To, more likely [Hobgoblins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobgoblin) but she'd used "goblin" for another task so they revert to being elves, note the Dobby reference.

Answer (score 11):

What I always thought was the "house" part of house-elf just referred to their slavery. Eg: "Dobby is a free-elf!" Not "Dobby is a free house-elf!" which makes me think that there are other elves maybe living in communities in magical forests/mountains etc.. probably avoiding wizards for fear of being enslaved. This is all just speculation though.